# Stochastic probability

Tags: probability

I have a question for stochastic calculus:

GIVEN: $M$ and $N$
 both independent random variables such that,

$M$ is Normal with mean $0$ and Variance $1$ &

$N$ is normal with mean $0$ and Variance $1$ .

Question:

Find $P(X+y<4)$

How do I do this?

I thought maybe I first re-write as

$P(X<Y-4)$

Then I feel we do some type of integral ?

Comment: Hint:  If $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal means $0$ variances $1$, then  $X+Y$ is normal mean $0$ variance $1+1$.

Comment: $M,N,X,Y,y\,\,$?